# Using the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for below android 11 devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm creating a file manager app for which I need the All files access permission and for which the target SDK has to be 30 and above as per play store requirements. Will having the  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission be enough for my use on all the android versions i.e work for android 10 devices and below or is it only applicable for android 11+?
If no,how do I gain such access for android 10 and below devices since the storage access framework won't be adequate for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are enough for your use case in pre Android 11 devices.

Long answer: Prior to the introduction of Android 10, there was no such thing as scoped storage; that is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would be sufficient for a file manager since you wouldn't be restricted to reading your app's dirs. After Android 11, Google changed things and "scoped" your write access to your dirs and your dirs alone (unless you got MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and got the user to consent to all files access in system prefs).

Comment: Ok,I was thinking once the target version is SDK 30 then your app would have to use scoped storage,wether its an android 11 device or not.

Comment: From these,the permissions I have to include are: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE requestlegacyexternalstorage = "true". Then,use the storage access framework for write access to SD Card on android 10 and below. Am I correct?